# Angular 4 Pipe Filter

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I am trying to use a custom pipe to filter my `*ngFor` loop using an input field with ngModel. With my other custom pipe (sortBy), it works perfectly fine. However, the filter pipe seems to make it that none of the data appears. I'm still learning this, and I tried a few variations to no avail:

```
-filter: term
-filter: {{term}}
-filter: 'term'
-filter" {{'term'}}
```

So I think the problem may lie elsewhere in the code. If anyone can help I'd really appreciate it.

Here is my code:

**HTML Component**

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{title}}!!
  </h1>

</div>
<h2>Please choose your favorite song: </h2>
<form id="filter">
    <label>Filter people by name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="term" [(ngModel)]="term" />
</form>


<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Likes</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let song of songs | filter:term| sortBy: 'likes'; let i  = index">
        <td>{{song.title}}</td>
        <td>{{song.artist}}</td>
        <td>{{song.likes}} 

            <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"  *ngIf="song.likes < 1"></i>
         <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" *ngIf="song.likes >= 1"></i>
             <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" (click)="addLike(i)" ></i>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" (click)="removeLike(i)" ></i>

          </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**PIPE**

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filter',
    pure: false
})

export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any {
        return items.filter(item => item.id.indexOf(args[0]) !== -1);
    }
}
```

Module

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SortByPipe } from './sort-by.pipe';
import { FilterPipe } from './filter.pipe';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'; 


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SortByPipe,
   FilterPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

JS COMPONENT

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Oxcord';
  songs = [

  {title: "Song", artist: "Artist", likes: 1},
  {title: "Chanson", artist: "Artiste", likes: 3},
  {title: "ABC", artist: "OneTwoThree", likes: 2},
  {title: "Trash", artist: "Meek Mill", likes: 0}

  ];
  addLike(input){
  this.songs[input].likes +=1;
} 
removeLike(input){
  this.songs[input].likes -=1;
} 
args="Me";
}
```

Comment: You're passing a single variable `array` as parameter to your `filter` *Pipe*, but there you're expecting an `array`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is a working plunkr with a filter and sortBy pipe. https://plnkr.co/edit/vRvnNUULmBpkbLUYk4uw?p=preview

As developer033 mentioned in a comment, you are passing in a single value to the filter pipe, when the filter pipe is expecting an array of values. I would tell the pipe to expect a single value instead of an array

```
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], term: string): any {
        // I am unsure what id is here. did you mean title?
        return items.filter(item => item.id.indexOf(term) !== -1);
    }
}
```

I would agree with DeborahK that impure pipes should be avoided for performance reasons. The plunkr includes console logs where you can see how much the impure pipe is called.

Comment: Thank you!! If I should a avoid such a pipe, what do you suggest I do instead?

Comment: @user3523602 I would do something along the lines of this https://plnkr.co/edit/cAfZdqU2ZqTkLcOoIaWW?p=preview This puts the filtering behind an observable sequence, so you can control the flow of filtering better (debounce + distinctUntilChanged)

Comment: can you tell me how to create a filter for particular column

Answer (score 17):

The transform method signature changed somewhere in an RC of Angular 2. Try something more like this:

```
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], filterBy: string): any {
        return items.filter(item => item.id.indexOf(filterBy) !== -1);
    }
}
```

And if you want to handle nulls and make the filter case insensitive, you may want to do something more like the one I have here:

```
export class ProductFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: IProduct[], filterBy: string): IProduct[] {
        filterBy = filterBy ? filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase() : null;
        return filterBy ? value.filter((product: IProduct) =>
            product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1) : value;
    }
}
```

And NOTE: Sorting and filtering in pipes is a big issue with performance and they are *NOT* recommended. See the docs here for more info: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: *"The transform method signature changed somewhere in an RC of Angular 2. Try something more like this:"* - What do you mean? There's absolutely no problem in use `transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any { ... }`, but, of course, if you do this, you have to pass parameters inside `array`, like this: `<div *ngFor="let song of songs | filter: [term]"...`

Comment: This is from the change log *"pipes now take a variable number of arguments, and not an array that contains all arguments."* from 2.0.0-beta.16 at this link: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md But yes, if you pass it an array then the argument is an array.

Comment: Thank you! I used the code provide by LLai, but added some of yours to make it case insensitive and it works great. Since sorting is fitlering using pipes is an issue, could you explain a better way I could make this functionality work?

Comment: The link I provided covered this: "The Angular team and many experienced Angular developers strongly recommend moving filtering and sorting logic into the component itself. The component can expose a filteredHeroes or sortedHeroes property and take control over when and how often to execute the supporting logic. Any capabilities that you would have put in a pipe and shared across the app can be written in a filtering/sorting service and injected into the component."

Comment: The link is not working anymore. Is filtering via pipe still not recommended?

Comment: It is still not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

[Pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) in Angular 2+ are a great way to transform and format data right from your templates.

Pipes allow us to change data inside of a template; i.e. filtering, ordering, formatting dates, numbers, currencies, etc. A quick example is you can transfer a string to lowercase by applying a simple filter in the template code.

List of Built-in Pipes from [API List](https://angular.io/api?type=pipe) <sup>[Examples](https://alligator.io/angular/built-in-pipes-angular/)</sup>

```
{{ user.name | uppercase }}
```

---

Example of Angular version 4.4.7. `ng version`

---

[**Custom Pipes**](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-pipes-angular/) which accepts multiple arguments.

```
HTML « *ngFor="let student of students | jsonFilterBy:[searchText, 'name'] "
TS   « transform(json: any[], args: any[]) : any[] { ... }
```

Filtering the content using a Pipe « `json-filter-by.pipe.ts`

```javascript
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'jsonFilterBy' })
@Injectable()
export class JsonFilterByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(json: any[], args: any[]) : any[] {
    var searchText = args[0];
    var jsonKey = args[1];

    // json = undefined, args = (2) [undefined, "name"]
    if(searchText == null || searchText == 'undefined') return json;
    if(jsonKey    == null || jsonKey    == 'undefined') return json;

    // Copy all objects of original array into new Array.
    var returnObjects = json;
    json.forEach( function ( filterObjectEntery ) {

      if( filterObjectEntery.hasOwnProperty( jsonKey ) ) {
        console.log('Search key is available in JSON object.');

        if ( typeof filterObjectEntery[jsonKey] != "undefined" && 
        filterObjectEntery[jsonKey].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) > -1 ) {
            // object value contains the user provided text.
        } else {
            // object didn't match a filter value so remove it from array via filter
            returnObjects = returnObjects.filter(obj => obj !== filterObjectEntery);
        }
      } else {
        console.log('Search key is not available in JSON object.');
      }

    })
    return returnObjects;
  }
}
```

Add to **`@NgModule`** « Add **`JsonFilterByPipe`** to your declarations list in your module; if you forget to do this you'll get an error no provider for **`jsonFilterBy`**. *If you add to module then it is available to all the component's of that module.*

```javascript
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [ StudentDetailsService ],
  declarations: [
    UsersComponent, UserComponent,

    JsonFilterByPipe,
  ],
  exports : [UsersComponent, UserComponent]
})
export class UsersModule {
    // ...
}
```

File Name: `users.component.ts` and `StudentDetailsService` is created from [this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-service-example?file=app%2Fservice%2Fmock-students.ts).

```javascript
import { MyStudents } from './../../services/student/my-students';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { StudentDetailsService } from '../../services/student/student-details.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './users.component.css' ],

  providers:[StudentDetailsService]
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy  {

  students: MyStudents[];
  selectedStudent: MyStudents;

  constructor(private studentService: StudentDetailsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadAllUsers();
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    // ONDestroy to prevent memory leaks
  }

  loadAllUsers(): void {
    this.studentService.getStudentsList().then(students => this.students = students);
  }

  onSelect(student: MyStudents): void {
    this.selectedStudent = student;
  }

}
```

File Name: `users.component.html`

```html
<div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6" >
            Filter by Name: 
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchText" 
                   class="form-control" placeholder="Search By Category" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2>Present are Students</h2>
    <ul class="students">
    <li *ngFor="let student of students | jsonFilterBy:[searchText, 'name'] " >
        <a *ngIf="student" routerLink="/users/update/{{student.id}}">
            <span class="badge">{{student.id}}</span> {{student.name | uppercase}}
        </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but i think i have good solution. Comparing to other answers and also comparing to accepted, mine accepts multiple values. Basically filter object with key:value search parameters (also object within object). Also it works with numbers etc, cause when comparing, it converts them to string.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'filter'})
export class Filter implements PipeTransform {
    transform(array: Array<Object>, filter: Object): any {
        let notAllKeysUndefined = false;
        let newArray = [];

        if(array.length > 0) {
            for (let k in filter){
                if (filter.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                    if(filter[k] != undefined && filter[k] != '') {
                        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                            let filterRule = filter[k];

                            if(typeof filterRule === 'object') {
                                for(let fkey in filterRule) {
                                    if (filter[k].hasOwnProperty(fkey)) {
                                        if(filter[k][fkey] != undefined && filter[k][fkey] != '') {
                                            if(this.shouldPushInArray(array[i][k][fkey], filter[k][fkey])) {
                                                newArray.push(array[i]);
                                            }
                                            notAllKeysUndefined = true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                if(this.shouldPushInArray(array[i][k], filter[k])) {
                                    newArray.push(array[i]);
                                }
                                notAllKeysUndefined = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(notAllKeysUndefined) {
                return newArray;
            }
        }

        return array;
    }

    private shouldPushInArray(item, filter) {
        if(typeof filter !== 'string') {
            item = item.toString();
            filter = filter.toString();
        }

        // Filter main logic
        item = item.toLowerCase();
        filter = filter.toLowerCase();
        if(item.indexOf(filter) !== -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```