# How to get elements filtered in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I have my elements that are filtered by name through a field, I would like to get the ones that were filtered after being filtered. I need only those that have been filtered, so the code: (filteredItems = (items |orderBy:'order_prop' | filter:query | limitTo:4))

This code is for Angular JS - I need in Angular 7, how can I do it?

```
  <input ng-model="query">
     <div ng-repeat="item in (filteredItems = (items | 
      orderBy:'order_prop' | filter:query | limitTo:4))">
      {{item}}
     </div>

//filteredItems, take the items
```

I need to get Angular after 2, no longer the Angular JS, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#no-filter-pipe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769748/angular-4-pipe-filter

Comment: You don't need, nor should you use a pipe for filtering. Just Array.prototype.filter() and Array.prototype.slice().

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158817/angular-2-orderby-pipe

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky why would u ever say something like this?
hes using Angular, he should use angular pipes.

Comment: I would say it because for filtering and ordering, the Angular team suggests to NOT use pipes. "The Angular team and many experienced Angular developers strongly recommend moving filtering and sorting logic into the component itself." https://angular.io/guide/pipes#no-filter-pipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if someone has found a better solution let me know

```
//DOCUMENT HTML
<tr #var *ngFor="let cliente of clientesArray | filter:searchClient as 
results" attr.data-id="{{cliente.id}}" [ngClass]="{'selected': 
cliente.id==selectedCustomer}" (click)="customerSelected(cliente.id)">  
    <td class ="pl-4 font-size-15px text-custom"> {{cliente.id}} </td>                                                                                
    <td class="text-custom"> {{cliente.name}} </td>
</tr>

//COMPONENT TYPESCRIPT

@ViewChildren('var') createdItems;

let elementsArray: any[] = [];

for(let element of this.createdItems.toArray()){
  elementsArray.push(element.nativeElement.children);
}

let myElementsArrayObject: {id?: number, name?:string}[] = [];
let object: { id?:number, name?:string} = {};

for(var _i = 0; _i < elementsArray.length; _i++){      
     object.id = elementsArray[_i][0].innerText; // TEXT
     object.name = elementsArray[_i][1].innerText; //TEXT, ADD AS MANY ITEMS 
     YOU WANT

     myElementsArrayObject.push(object);              
}

console.log(myElementsArrayObject);
```