# Binding the piped result of an *ngFor to a global variable

Tags: angular

```
*ngFor="let item of items | filter:{ name: searchString } : searchString as filteredItems"
```

and later

```
<button (click)="doSomething(filteredItems)>
```

`filteredItems` is just a local variable that can be used inside *ngFor. How can I bind `filteredItems` to a global variable so I can submit all filtered items later when I press the button?

Comment: My second pla, `<button (click)="doSomething(items | filter:{ name: searchString } : searchString )>` did not work because filters are not allowed in action calls.

Comment: may i ask why you are using a pipe to filter? for what you want to do wouldn't it be easier to just have a filter function that returns your array and then store that array as a parameter of your component?

Comment: I thought a pipe to filter is the way to go. I followed guides likes this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769748/angular-4-pipe-filter and it works great, I am just having trouble to get the returns of it now later in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following
`

```html
<ng-container *ngIf=”(items | filter:searchString) as filteredItems”>

  <div *ngFor=”let item of filteredItems”>
    {{item}}
  </div>

  <p>Count: <b>{{filteredItems.length}}</b></p>
  
</ng-container>
```

then you will be able to use `filteredItems` as a variable.

However if you are wanting to run something on a button click, you shouldn't use Pipes, and instead write a function in your component.

Comment: Works. Thanks!
Why shouldn't I use pipes here?